Elsa.Webhooks.Extensions missing in any library older than 3.0.0
I'm trying to run the example apps laid out in the documentation, but if I try to use any Elsa library newer than version 3.0.0, I get a build error stating Elsa.Webhooks.Extensions is missing. What is the fix?
I tried versions 3.1.0 and up to 3.3.0-rc3 and get the same result.
